# Spring boot security, oauth2 and thymeleaf static resource cannot be found

Tags: java

I have added my css and js under Resource then static folder. When I access path  "forgotpassword" all my static resource are loaded correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qITWp.jpg)

However when I try to access the same path but this time with a trailing slash "forgotpassword/"  all my static resource are not loaded. I get status 404 not found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDSOL.jpg)

Here is my security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(-20)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    static private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Oauth2AuthserverApplication.class);

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/forgotpassword/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/forgotpassword/**", "/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access");
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems the issue is located in your template. You should not load your static file using a relative path ( js/my.js ) but using an absolute one : ( /js/my.js ) I hope it may help

Comment: Thank you. Its working, and for css this is what i had  to do th:href="@{/css/Default/css/style.css}" and for js  th:src="@{/js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js}"

Answer (score 0):

For css this is what i had to do `th:href="@{/css/Default/css/style.css}"` 
and for js `th:src="@{/js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js}"`